# Member$ application in clips

Tags: clips

This is the question I am faced with:
Depending on the type of the JDB, write a rule stipulating what to do when a JDB is in LTB or LTH. using member$

Initialisation:

```
(defrule to-do
(declare (salience -20))
(bus (id-jdb ?bus)(type ?type))
(LTB (id-jdb ?ltb))
(LTH (id-jdb ?lth))
(test (member$ ?id-jdb ?bus))
=>
(printout t " the JDB is " crlf))`
```

I don't know how to apply member$ so that it gives back either LTB or LTH.

Answer (score 0):

If ?bus contains the type of the JDB, you can do this:

```
(defrule to-do
   (declare (salience -20))
   (bus (id-jdb ?bus) (type ?type))
   (LTB (id-jdb ?ltb))
   (LTH (id-jdb ?lth))
   (test (member$ ?bus (create$ LTB LTH)))
   =>
   (printout t " the JDB is " crlf))
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
(defrule to-do
   (declare (salience -20))
   (bus (id-jdb ?bus&LTB|LTH) (type ?type))
   (LTB (id-jdb ?ltb))
   (LTH (id-jdb ?lth))
   =>
   (printout t " the JDB is " crlf))
```